# Find max and max value of the date range ( user selection )

Tags: postgresql, cognos-10

I am trying to find the max, min value based on date range selected by user. 
The column name : sysname , datetime , node_availability. 
Currently, the query using postgres such below

```
SELECT sysname,
       max(node_availability),
       min(node_availability)
FROM cust_eq_avail_dy 
WHERE datetime BETWEEN datetime AND datetime
GROUP BY sysname
```

Once this works, I will put the sql in the Cognos report. The problem is at the condition date range `where datetime between datetime and datetime`.

Cognos has two(2) date prompts of datetime; parameters `Start` and `End` and they will set at the details filter.

Someone can help me to correct the query?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It seems like you just need something like `where datetime between start and end`.

Comment: I don't know how to improve at condition " where datetime between start and end " . i have set it before but the result is not i want. I need to find way to relate my date prompt which carry two paramaters : Start ; End .  The idea is :    select hostname, min(value), max(value)
        from cust_eq_ping_dy
        WHERE datetime BETWEEN ?Start? and ?End?
        group by hostname .  I got error if do like this. Error on the datetime is not existed.

Comment: Then the column `datetime` doesn't exist. How does your table look like? What columns do you have? Add the table definition to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never heard of Cognos, a bit of googling suggests this should work:

```
WHERE datetime BETWEEN ?Start? and ?End?
```

You might want to investigate `in_range()`.